# ArgumentException on MediaElement AreTransportControlsEnabled property set (Windows Phone 8.1)

Tags: c#, exception, windows-phone-8.1, mediaelement

I am developing Windows Phone application and I got a really weird exception when I set my `MediaElement` object property `AreTransportControlsEnabled` to some value:

```
        _mediaElement.IsFullWindow = fullScreen;
        _mediaElement.AreTransportControlsEnabled = fullScreen;
```

This is what that I get:

> Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in MyApp.ni.EXE WinRT
>   information: The value cannot be infinite or Not a Number (NaN).
>   Additional information: The parameter is incorrect.
>
> The value cannot be infinite or Not a Number (NaN).

How boolean value can be a `NAN` or in finite and why it's allways throws the exception on the `AreTransportControlsEnabled` boolean property and not on `IsFullWindow`?

This issue is still hunting me...2 months gone now...

Comment: what is the value for fullScreen when exception occurs? and also are you adding custom transport controls?

Comment: When I get the exceptiokn the value of the IsFullWindow propert was false and I did set it to false. I am developing on Windows Phone 8.1 so I don't really have custom transport controls I can only hide or show some of them..